# When to use MIMEMultipart() From and To

Tags: python, email

Most examples of sending email from Python seem to set the From and To attributes of `email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart` similar to the following:

```
msg = email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = from_email
msg['To'] = to_email
msg['Subject'] = subject
```

Then, the email is sent using `smtplib.SMTP()` where the original recipient and the sender values are used, like this:

```
s = smtplib .SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(from_email, to_email,  msg.as_string())
```

So what’s the point of setting msg[‘From’] and msg[‘To’] when it’s not used.  And in what situation would you use it?

See this for an example of where both are set: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set 'From' at 2 places because one is for the actual sending, and the other is for *displaying* where the message comes from.
Note that most SMTP clients at this point do not allow you to adapt the From header (except for giving an alias, rather than changing the From email)

Something like

```
Your Neighbour <my@email.com>
```

Could be valid as from header, while

```
Your Neighbour <fake@email.com>
```

is not allowed (when sending originally from `my@email.com`).